# retrieving values in array & store in session and calling to other page asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net

Hi
I want to store values inside the array in session. I want to use it to another page. How i can do that?
I used session to store values of array as follow:

```
    int i, randno;
    int[] a = new int[5];
        for ( i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            int flag = 0;
            Random rnd = new Random();
            randno = rnd.Next(1, 15);
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {
                if (a[j] == randno)
                    flag = 1;
            }
            if (flag == 0)
            {
                a[i] = randno;

            }
            else
            {
                i--;
            }

        }
Session["values"] = a;
```

In other page i used code:

```
int[] a = (int[])Session["values"];
Response.Write(a);
```

This code is right? 
Because its not giving values.
But retrieving to another page then it gives last value of the array, on the same page it gives all the values. I want all the values of the array.
Asp.net, c#
Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

To store all items of the array.

```
string[] a = new string[]{"a","b","c"};
Session["values"] = a;
```

And in the next page, you can retrieve it like this.

```
string[] a = (string[])Session["values"]
```

Comment: I used in the same way but it gives output:System.Int32[]. No values are retrieved

Comment: I didn't get you. Where you are getting this? What is a?

Comment: Oh you modified the question. You are getting System.Int32[] while you are doing a response.Write? This is because you cannot print an array directly. You need to do a loop and try. Try this. foreach(int i in a){ Response.Write(i.ToString());}

Comment: still it gives System.Int32[]System.Int32[]System.Int32[]System.Int32[]System.Int32[] when i used response.write in foreach loop

Comment: @Anuraj give me idea how i can use those values in function. I have getquestion(int no) function . I have to use those array values in place of no in that function. Is their any way to do that like index?

Comment: call it in the loop like this for(int i in a){ getquestion(i); }

Comment: @Anuraj Can you help me in my applicaion. I have one label for question & another radiobuttonlist for their answers and next button.When i click to next button next question appears.I have preview question link at last. When i click link then it shows checkboxes. suppose i click on 1st & 3rd checkboxes then it should go to 1st question with earlier selected answer. after clicking next button it should go to 3rd question with earlier selected answer. here i can change 1st & 3rd questions answers as i selected only 1st & 3rd checkbox in preview link. how i can do this?

Answer (score 2):

You could store the entire array into session:

```
Session["values"] = a;
```

and on the other page:

```
SomeType[] a = Session["values"] as SomeType[];
// Use the array here
```

Comment: i used that but it gives output: System.Int32[]

Comment: I did in that way. I posted my code.values are not coming still it gives output : System.Int32[]

Answer (score 0):

The probblem you are facing is in the last line of code:

```
Response.Write(a);
```

It's like ytou are saying

```
int[].ToString()
```

and normally, the output will be as you have it right now.

My take will be to store the data as string array and then you can represent it like this:

```
Response.Write(string.Join(", ", a));
```

Answer (score 0):

YOu could put it in a class, like so:

Public Class MyGlobals

Private Shared _QuizArray As New ArrayList

Public Property theArray As ArrayList

Get

```
Return _theArray
```

End Get

Set(ByVal value As ArrayList)

```
_theArray = value
```

End Set

End Property

End Class

Then Access it from various pages like this:

Set Value:     QuizArray.Add(index)

Get Value:    i = QuizArray(index)